# chosen-select doesnt work on adding new row from codeigniter-php code through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I am executing an ajax script which loads a view into a div. The view populates some dropdowns from the database. When this view is loaded into the div, chosen-select doesnt work.
If I try to call

```
$('.chosen-select').chosen('destroy');
$('.chosen-select').chosen();
```

inside success block of ajax call, it says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function
```

If we call these functions outside ajax call function block, it has no effect.
Below is my js

```
function addnewrow()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "mycontroller/myfunction",
        success: function(res){
            if(res) {
                var list = document.querySelectorAll(".newrow");
                var last = list[list.length - 1];
                last.innerHTML=res; 
                //$('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');
                var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
                newDiv.setAttribute("class", "newrow");
                newDiv.setAttribute("id", "newrow");
                newDiv.innerHTML = "";
                last.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", newDiv);
            }
        },
        error: function(res, status, error) {
            alert('Please Refresh the page and Try Again.');
        }
    });
}
```

Below is my controller function which prepares the page with dropsowns and pass the result to js

```
public function myfunction()
{
    $data["data1"]=$this->main_model->getdata1();
    $data["data2"]=$this->main_model->getdata2();
    $data["data3"]=$this->main_model->getdata3();
    $this->load->view('myviews/datapage',$data);
}
```

Below is the target code for reference which needs to be passed to js and then is placed inside newrow

```
<div class="row">
    <br>
    <div class="col-sm-2">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label>DATALIST 1</label>
        <?php
            if(isset($data1) && !empty($data1))
            {
                echo '<select class="chosen-select form-control" id="datalist1" name="datalist1[]" data-placeholder="Choose an data item">
                    <option value="">  </option>';
                foreach($data1 as $s)
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$s->sno.'">'.$s->dataname.'</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" id="itemdetails">
        <!--
            ON SELECTING AN ITEM IN DATALIST1, FETCH SOME DATA FROM DATABASE ABOUT THAT ITEM AND SHOW IT HERE
        -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label>DATALIST 2</label>
        <?php
            if(isset($data2) && !empty($data2))
            {
                echo '<select class="chosen-select form-control" id="datalist2" name="datalist2[]" data-placeholder="Choose a Data">
                    <option value="">  </option>';
                foreach($data2 as $s)
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$s->sno.'">'.$s->dataname.'</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label>DATALIST 3</label>
        <?php
            if(isset($data2) && !empty($data2))
            {
                echo '<select class="chosen-select form-control" id="datalist3" name="datalist3[]" data-placeholder="Choose a Data">
                    <option value="">  </option>';
                foreach($data2 as $s)
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$s->sno.'">'.$s->dataname.'</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-1">
        <br>
        <div class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4" name="removerows" onclick="removethisrow(this);"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
I tried using 3.3.1 version of JQuery, 1.8.7 version of chosen, 4.0.6-rc.0 version of select2 in place of chosen and I face the same issues everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding setTimeOut() to the chosen initialisation as follows.

```
function addnewrow()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "mycontroller/myfunction",
        success: function(res){
            if(res) {
                var list = document.querySelectorAll(".newrow");
                var last = list[list.length - 1];
                last.innerHTML=res; 
                setTimeOut(function() {
                   $('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');
                }, 1000);
                var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
                newDiv.setAttribute("class", "newrow");
                newDiv.setAttribute("id", "newrow");
                newDiv.innerHTML = "";
                last.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", newDiv);
            }
        },
        error: function(res, status, error) {
            alert('Please Refresh the page and Try Again.');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This had no effect. No erros, no positive results.